# How to connect ag-grid (Live Streaming) to lightstreamer?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, lightstreamer

I want to connect ag-grid to lightstreamer as a socket.
Does ag-grid support?

Comment: You should check ag-grid docs more better

Answer (score 1):

I've not used lightstreamer before, but based on their documentation it looks like it's a way of fetching data real time as a subscription.

I've implemented it here as a starting point that you can use, see the [following plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ahKmmsK2p0AmRgwE)

Note that all I've done here is added the logic from the [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightstreamer-client-web) inside the Grid Event onGridReady:

```
  onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent) {
    var sub = new Subscription(
      'MERGE',
      ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'],
      ['stock_name', 'last_price']
    );
    sub.setDataAdapter('QUOTE_ADAPTER');
    sub.setRequestedSnapshot('yes');
    sub.addListener({
      onItemUpdate: (obj) => {
        const stockName = obj.getValue('stock_name');
        const lastPrice = obj.getValue('last_price');
        const newData = [
          ...this.rowData,
          { stock_name: stockName, last_price: lastPrice },
        ];
        this.rowData = newData;
      },
    });
    var client = new LightstreamerClient(
      'http://push.lightstreamer.com',
      'DEMO'
    );
    client.connect();
    client.subscribe(sub);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the result but I need  output like https://demos.lightstreamer.com/StockListDemo_Frames/
in ag-grid.

Comment: I'm not familiar on lightstreamer so I can't help you there I'm afraid. The sample I sent you is a POC to show you that you can use it, and it should be enough for you to implement your use case.